# Leaflet JS: On click a MarkerClusterGroup, check/uncheck a control.layer checkbox

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

How to check a checkbox of the control.layer when I click on a cluster?

Example: When I click on my cluster "Bosquet Creux" on my map, I want it to check "Bosquet Creux" in my layer control.

[My Leaflet Map](http://91.121.3.77/ori-dynamic-map/)

Plugin used: [MarkersCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

```
var Region1 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({ showCoverageOnHover: false, disableClusteringAtZoom: 4, maxClusterRadius: 300,
iconCreateFunction: function(cluster){
    var Region1 = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
        var n = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < Region1.length; i++)
            return L.divIcon({ html: n, className: 'Region1', iconSize: L.point(268, 34)});

        Region1.on('click', function(){if (map.hasLayer(Region2)) {map.removeLayer(Region2);}});
}
});
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Add this in your callback function `Region.on('click', function() { /*somewhere here*/ })`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724768/activate-or-check-checkbox-with-onchange-event-from-dropdown

Comment: I've added this: `Region1.on('click', function() {(map.addLayer(Region1).checked = true);});` but it dosen't work.

Comment: And this: `Region1.on('click', function(){(region1.setVisibility(checked));});` doesn't work too

Comment: This `Region1.onclick = function(){(map.setLayer(Region1).checked = true);};` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To check for a click on a cluster you can listen to the `clusterclick` event as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#events). You can then find the checkbox with `document.querySelector('#id of checkbox')` (or `document.getElementById()`) and turn it on by setting its value `.checked="checked"`, or turn it off with `.checked=false`.

Place this code outside of the `new L.MarkerClusterGroup()` somewhere in your Javascript:

```
Region1.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    if (!map.hasLayer(Region2)) {
      map.addLayer(Region2);
      map.removeLayer(Region1);
      document.querySelector('#region1checkbox').checked="checked";
    }
});
```

Another note: Your `Region1.on()` in the code you posted is not executed because there's a `return` statement before it, this will cause the function to return the icon and it will end right there.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/83oEg9tbeAeGwq8ZPPmi?p=preview

Comment: Hi @OziBaldone, I'm glad to hear that it works! If you think this answer solves this question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)